# How to call a method from a object instance that is being used by a thread?

Tags: c++

Given a class in `MyTimer.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyTimer {
private:
   bool active = false;

public:
   void run() {
      active = true;
      while (active) {
         cout << "I am running\n";
         Sleep(1000);
      };
   }
   void stop() {
      active = false;
   }
};
```

When I execute `run()` method in a thread, it will run a loop printing `"I am running"` every second.

I would like to stop the loop by executing `stop()` which will set `active` to `false` and that should stop the loop, however it does not stop and it keeps printing `"I am running"`.

```
#include "MyTimer.h"
#include <thread>
int main(){
    MyTimer myTimer;
    std::thread th(&MyTimer::run, myTimer);
    Sleep(5000);
    myTimer.stop(); // It does not stop :(
    while (true); // Keeping this thread running
}
```

I am not familiarized of how objects work in C++ threads so I hope there is a solution for this

Comment: Where's the `th.join();`?  Why isn't it `std::atomic<bool> active;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. `active` should be declared as a `std::atomic <bool>`.  Without this, changes made in one thread may not be seen by another (the compiler might optimise out the check).
2. `std::thread th(&MyTimer::run, myTimer);` *copies* `myTimer`.  Instead, you want `std::thread th(&MyTimer::run, &myTimer);`.
3. `while (true);` is better expressed as `th.join ()`, because (a) this doesn't busy loop, and (b) it allows the program to exit when the thread terminates.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h9UN5mklY3c5iTUW)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the solution! Didn't know about atomics and the difference using or not using"&"

Comment: Can you elaborate on 1 ?

Comment: @AmitG. `std::atomic` is designed for communicating between threads.  Non-atomic variables are not.  If the compiler can see that `active` doesn't change in the loop, and it is not declared `atomic`, then it is within its rights to optimise out the check (according to the ['as-if rule'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)).  I don't think this actually happens for member variables in practise, but you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @AmitG. Nonetheless you should use them, if you want to be sure that your program is going to run correctly on all platforms.  They exist for a reason.

Comment: @AmitG. "When an evaluation of an expression writes to a memory location and another evaluation reads or modifies the same memory location, the expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting evaluations has a data race unless both evaluations execute on the same thread or in the same signal handler, or
both conflicting evaluations are atomic operations (see std::atomic), or
one of the conflicting evaluations happens-before another (see std::memory_order)
If a data race occurs, the behavior of the program is undefined."

Comment: Revevantly "it works as I want it *right now*" is the most insidious symptom of undefined behaviour, because any change in the program could potentially make that "it's broken now"

Comment: You are wrong, that's exactly what a race condition *is*. "happens-before" is a term defined in memory order, in general there *is no* "the last operation"

Comment: @Caleth, in race condition one of the thread 'wins'. if 2 threads write fixed value: 'false' to 'bool active'. Who cares who wins? In both cases the result is the same.

Comment: A race condition is undefined behaviour. That can mean *anything* You might not have any bool, or any program, or you might have nonsensical unrelated data

Comment: Also I doubt "atomic operations reduce performance" is even generally true at the level of granularity C++ gives you for specifying atomic operations. What it does is *guarantee* that you get the behaviour that you desire, rather than relying on the whim of the implementation